# How to reverse JSON JTOKEN c#

Tags: c#, json, reverse

How to reverse JToken values? I have a JToken as input and need to have JToken as output.

A can do "`jtoken.Reverse()`", but this method returns `IEnumerable<JToken>`

Example of JToken:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "body": "steel",
      "can_fly": 1,
      "hover": 1
    },
```

....many many items

Comment: What type is your `jtoken`? It's likely to be some collection, not just a plain `JToken`... Your example is not helpful as it's JSON which is - even though your question is about a JSON library - totally unrelated.

Comment: Show the code where a value is assigned to your `jtoken`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This return value means that `Reverse()` does not create a new array (or whatever kind of collection your `jtoken` is) but an iterator that will yield elements in the reverse order.

If you just need to iterate over the tokens then do so:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> reversed = jtoken.Reverse();
foreach(var token in reversed)` {
    // do stuff; token is a JToken here
}
```

Comment: I have a method which expects (JToken source), and I can't change this method, it used by many functions.

Comment: hmm.you are right, I changed also main cycle for int by foreach and all works, thaks.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use:

```
JToken reversed = new JArray(jToken.Reverse());
```

Comment: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.

Comment: Edited - try using new JArray instead